# Какой планировщик постов использовать для Инстаграм?

Tags: instagram

Всем привет!

Уже около недели ищу планировщик постов для Инстаграм, потому что Meta Business Suit меня не устраивает.

Сегодня подключил триалку SMMBOX, но, как оказалось, они ориентированы не на Инстаграм, а больше на ВК и ОК :(
У SMMBOX нет очень нужной мне пакетной загрузки stories и reels, пакетом он умеет грузить только посты, что хорошо, но мало..

Мне нужен планировщик для Инсты, который позволял бы пакетами грузить помимо постов ещё stories и reels.

Вы можете посоветовать сервис? Платный или бесплатный значения не имеет.